# Unable to delete subnet and virtual network in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am just practicing the azure. And I created a virtual network and subnets.

Now I am not able to delete the subnet. I have disconnected all connected devices from the virtual network.

[image]

Here is the error getting while deleting subnet
[image]

Please help me to clean up the subnet and virtual network.

Thanks

**Additional details**

All resources in my account
[image]

And here is the subnets tab and error getting while deletion:
[image]

Subnet configuration:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you have an App Service  endpoint connected to the Subnet.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.... I have deleted all the app services in my account but still not able to delete the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows the subnet `PrivateSubnet` should be in use. And you can see it's delegated to the service `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`. So you need to remove the delegated service first. Do it follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-subnet-delegation#delegate-a-subnet-to-an-azure-service). When the delegated service list is empty, then you can delete the subnet as you want.

**Update:**

According to my experience, your subnet is in use `network/PrivateSubnet/AppLink`, it means there is a Web App integrate with your subnet at least. And I didn't see the Web App in your resource group. So I guess there someone else uses your subnet and his Web App still exists. You need to check it yourself.

Comment: Charles, I tried updating subnet delegation to "None" but it is not updating and getting error.

Comment: @NareshEde Can you share more details? The connected devices and the what is the subnet now.

Comment: Charles, I have updated my original post with more screenshots. can you take a look once?

Thanks

Comment: @NareshEde What is the error when you update subnet delegation to "None"? As I see you do not have Web service in the group. Someone else uses your resource?

Comment: @NareshEde Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?